# How to perform pandas column shift in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Lets assume we have a dataset with the following data:

```
timestamp,col1

1533286270,1
1533286271,2
1533286272,3
1533286273,4
1533286274,5
```

I want to get preceding `col1` value in the `col1_prev` to be able to compare them. The result should be the same as `pandas.shift(-1)`.

How to achieve this functionality with plain SQL query?

Query result should look like this:

```
timestamp,col1,col1_prev

1533286270,1,NULL
1533286271,2,1
1533286272,3,2
1533286273,4,3
1533286274,5,4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `lag()` function is one way:

```
WITH
  input AS (
  SELECT
    1533286270 AS timestamp,
    1 AS col1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    1533286271 AS timestamp,
    2 AS col1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    1533286272 AS timestamp,
    3 AS col1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    1533286273 AS timestamp,
    4 AS col1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    1533286274 AS timestamp,
    5 AS col1 )
SELECT
  timestamp,
  col1,
  LAG(col1) OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS col1_prev
FROM
  input
```

[image]

Comment: i think it is more relevant to use `LAG(col1) OVER(ORDER BY timestamp) AS col1_prev` here - just my 2 cents :o)

Comment: This is a fair point. Depends on what the OP wants to achieve and expected output. A simple change however :)